# how well do screwless wall plates work for outlets on tiled backsplashes

Tags: electrical

[image: wall plate]
I found these at menards and thought they were interesting, I wouldn't have to cut the tile around the screws. was wondering if anyone has tried them and what their experience was with them ?

Comment: You're still going to have to screw the receptacle to the box and the _inner_ cover plate to the receptacle. The inner cover plate then has something that these outer cover plates attach to. They're not just held on by magic. If you're thinking that you're going to not have to use screws of any sort, you are off base. Notice the white text on the black background: "No _visible_ screws".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They work just fine.

You will still probably have cut tile around screws- they have a backplate that installs with the same small screws as a standard "Decora" style outlet cover. The front plate simply snaps over that.

Comment: Was thinking something like that when I saw "no visible screws".  Usually means the screws are hidden.